# I need a different CPU cooler

Tags: processor, memory, cooling

I am sitting here with the following specs:

- Case: [Sharkoon REX8 Value Edition Black](https://www.sharkoon.com/product/1678/Rex8Val#desc)
- Motherboard: [Gigabyte GA-970-UD3](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3907#ov)
- CPU: [AMD FX-8320](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819113285)
- CPU cooler: [Thermalright Macho 120](http://www.thermalright.com/html/products/cpu_cooler/macho120.html)

When I first ordered my computer, I didn't think too much of upgrading but now I do. I wanted to install additional RAM, however, I noticed that the CPU cooler is too big and is effectively blocking my RAM slots.

(More specifically, the cooler blocks the first slot. Slot number two, three and four are free so I can place three RAM sticks at a maximum. Nevertheless I want to take advantage of the Dual Channel ability of my motherboard so I want to get 4x4 running and not 2x4 and 1x8.)

It would be nice if the new cooler is small enough to free up my RAM slot and also is suitable to overclock my AMD to 4.0 GHz.

Money doesn't pose a problem here.

If you need pictures or additional information, I am more than happy to share some.

Comment: Related answers on another question: http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/934/cpu-cooling-system-recommendation/936#936

Comment: For the record, you'll probably need LP (low profile) RAM sticks if your RAM slots are blocked by the HSF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest the [Cooler Master Hyper 212 EVO](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005O65JXI). For one the cooler you have is huge for a cooler and actually has a bunch of people worrying about the same problem you have. Because the EVO is not meant to do anything more than keep your CPU cool it is much smaller and pack almost the same punch as the Macho. In addition, the Macho is double the weight of the EVO. As far as I could tell you only need a CPU cooler and nothing more, and that's what the EVO will do for you.

Comment: I had the cooler running for a while now and it works amazingly well (the cooler could easily beat an 8h endurance test). Thanks for the recommendation!

Comment: You're quit welcome enjoy your computer!